# Скажите пожалуйста, у меня правильная ER-модель?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть задание, вот скрин:[image: Задание 1]

Нужно по нему сделать БД. С этим я справлюсь, но для начала решил сделать ER-модель и мне кажется, что в ней чего то не хватает. Подскажите, правильная ли моя ER-модель? Вот сама модель:

[image: Модель]

UPD:
Добавил связь товаров и заказов. Так лучше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, Вы сперва проанализируете? Определите, какие у Вас есть сущности, какие есть у них атрибуты, какие имеются между ними связи, какие процессы следует реализовывать? Без этой информации строить диаграмму - занятие малоосмысленное, даже если подсматривать на потолке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как  в задании указано, что один заказ соответствует одному товару, и при этом заказов такого товара может быть много, то необходимо установить связь между сущностями "товары" и "заказы" (связь будет один-ко-многим).

Со связью "товары" и "отгрузки" всё немного сложнее. В задании указано, что в отгрузке могут участвовать несколько товаров (т.е. много) и при этом одному товару могут советовать сразу несколько отгрузок. Это связь "многие-ко-многим". Дело в том, что не все СУБД могут поддерживать её реализацию, например, напрямую связать две таблицы в MS Access такой связью не получится, придется делать отдельную, промежуточную таблицу, которая будет объединять в себе данные из этих двух таблиц (это называется "связь через третью таблицу").

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Переделал как вы сказали. Так лучше стало?

Comment: @NeoShima, хотел уточнить, в какой СУБД собираетесь делать базу?

Comment: MySQL PhpMyAdmin

Comment: То есть, напишу код создания всей БД на sql и перенесу её в консоль в PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @NeoShima, я думаю, что в таком случае, чтобы связать товары и отгрузку необходимо сделать связь через третью таблицу. Этой третьей таблицей и будет выступать "заказы". Поэтому уберите связь между товарами и отгрузками (и поле "код товара" из отгрузок тоже удалите).

Comment: спасибо, сейчас уберу и попробую SQL написать.

Comment: @NeoShima, еще хотел бы уточнить про договоры. На Вашей диаграмме видно, что один заказ может иметь много договоров. То есть, если компания закажет какое-либо количество товара1 в определённую дату, то это означает, что на этот заказ можно оформить сразу несколько одинаковых договоров, что немного неправильно. Ведь каждый заказ уникален и он не может дублироваться (у него, например, будет всегда номер разный). Поэтому договор у определённого заказа может быть только один.

Comment: При этом, компания может заказать сразу несколько товаров и оформить всё это одним договором. Поэтому сделайте связь между "договор" и "заказ" один-ко-многим.

Comment: немного не понял о чём вы. У меня же договоры привязываются к заказу, то есть у каждого заказа свой договор. Разве не так? Что тогда нужно сделать?

Comment: @NeoShima, прошу прощения, немного неправильно понял диаграмму, моя вина). А так всё правильно.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное за помощь! Хорошего дня!

Comment: @NeoShima, благодарю, и Вам!)